# Amazon SES - Domain Verification Pending

Tags: amazon-web-services, email-server, amazon-route53, dkim, amazon-ses

I am trying to setup Amazon SES on my Route53 domain (writeurl.com). The domain verification status remains at pending verification and does not proceed. The following nslookup command does not show anything, even though the records are created in Route53 hosted zone.

```
nslookup -type=txt _amazonses.writeurl.com
```

What am I doing wrong here? Following are the Route53 records:

[image]

Comment: There are other records that also do not match, like the `MX` (showing GSuite servers, not SES). Are you sure the above screenshot is current, as it does not appear to match what records are currently present in more ways than just the _amazonses `TXT` record?

Comment: Yes its latest screenshot.

Comment: What's going on with the wildcard record?

Comment: @MichaelHampton you mean *.writeurl.com ?

Comment: That's the only wildcard record I see above. Did you have even more of them?

Comment: No, its the only one. So its there to handle www.writeurl.com

Comment: Do you really need a wildcard record? They're not generally a good idea, and I'd recommend you get rid of it and put in the actual records you need.

Comment: Ok i just did it. Replaced it with www.writeurl.com

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the DNS record you are modifying is not current. You need to talk to Amazon and figure out why the records shown in Route53 are not the same as the records exposed to the Internet.

If I do an `nslookup -type=SOA` on writeurl.com I see the SOA for that domain is `ns-232.awsdns-29.com`. Your screenshot shows SOA is `ns-696.awsdns-23.net`. I would think that was an alias, but the TXT record you show in your screenshot for google site verification does not match what's exposed to an nslookup from here, and doing a lookup of your MX records here shows three, none of which match the one in your screenshot. SES can't use that string to validate because it can't see it.